# Properties Accessor Method Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm trying to make another custom view available at rood VC's viewdidload.

```
MSHView *customTextView = [[MSHView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
customTextView.textView.text = @"abc";
[customTextView layoutSubviews];
[self.view addSubview:customTextView];
```

MSHView Header file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UITextView * textView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* translucentIV;
```

MSHView implementaion file:

```
-(UIImageView*) translucentIV {
    if(!_translucentIV) {
        _translucentIV.frame = self.frame;
        //NSLog(@"frame for translucent IV, %@", _translucentIV.frame);
        _translucentIV.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _translucentIV.alpha = 0.5;
    }
    return _translucentIV;
}

-(UITextView* ) textView{
    if(!_textView){
        /*
        float height = self.bounds.size.height - 5;
        float width = self.bounds.size.width - 5;
        _textView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,width,height);
        _textView.text = @"test text";
         */
        NSLog(@"textview property being initialized");
    }
    return _textView;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    self.textView.frame = self.frame;
    self.translucentIV.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.alpha = 0.5;
    NSString *abc = @"abc";
    self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",abc];
    NSLog(@"layout subview being called");
}


-(void) setTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    if(textView != _textView) {
        _textView = textView;
        _textView.text = @"setter method called";
    }

}
```

Still cannot see the textview from MSHView. I think I'm not doing properties properly. any help or explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't actually assign an allocated-initialized instance to the `_translucentIV` and `_textView` variables. They stay there being `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating the `UIImageView` and `UITextView`.

Try something more like:

```
-(UIImageView*) translucentIV {
    if(!_translucentIV) {
        _translucentIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        //NSLog(@"frame for translucent IV, %@", _translucentIV.frame);
        _translucentIV.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _translucentIV.alpha = 0.5;
    }
    return _translucentIV;
}

-(UITextView *)textView {
    if(!_textView) {
        float height = self.bounds.size.height - 5;
        float width = self.bounds.size.width - 5;
        _textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,width,height)];
    }
    return _textView;
}
```

You'll also want to add them to the parent view somewhere.

Comment: within these if I do [self addSubView:_translucentIV]; that doesn't work

Comment: Try [self addSubView:self.translucentIV]

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I went a different way, but your pointed me in correct direction. I basically had to allocate and add to subview.